# Javascript 'while' loop to load single page App does not work

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to load a single page app until I have certain number of Items.
My function passes the correct new *scrollHeight* but the code does not work.
Here is my code, I start it by calling *scrollInitiate()* function. What am I missing?

```
function wait(ms){
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    var end = start;
    while(end < start + ms) {
      end = new Date().getTime();
   }
 }


function scrollInitiate() {
    while ($x('//*[@id="items"]/container').length < 200) {
        console.log("attempting");
        wait(5000);
        scrollIt(document.scrollingElement.scrollHeight);
    }
}

function scrollIt(height) {
    console.log("scrolling to: " + height);
    document.scrollingElement.scrollTo(0, height);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `while` to wait in javascript, due to javascript blocking nature. Instead use `setTimeout`:

```
function scrollInitiate() {
  if ($x('//*[@id="items"]/container').length < 200) {
    console.log("attempting");
    scrollIt(document.scrollingElement.scrollHeight);
    setTimeout(scrollInitiate, 5000);
  }
  console.log("success");
}
```

Comment: Blocking was causing it to fail. Thank you.